# How do I prevent my opengraph action stories from being aggregated in the news feed?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-feed, facebook-stream-story

I have an OpenGraph action posting working. It appears as I want in the timeline, but only appears as an aggregation in the newsfeed, without any of the story attachments. How can I make it appear the same way in the newsfeed as it appears in the timeline?

For reference, here are screen shots of the timeline version (which is what I want), and the feed version (which is aggregated, against my wishes):

Timeline version of the posting:
[timeline story posting http://a.yfrog.com/img580/6074/7ohf.png](http://a.yfrog.com/img580/6074/7ohf.png)

News feed version of the posting (an aggregate which includes past test cases):
[feed story posting http://a.yfrog.com/img849/2553/9z2.png](http://a.yfrog.com/img849/2553/9z2.png)

edited 11/15/12:
We have a second open graph action that DOESN'T do the above, but instead looks the same in the timeline and the feed (which is what we want).

Timeline version:
[image: timeline story posting]
<sub>(source: [yfrog.com](http://a.yfrog.com/img534/5502/ucm.png))</sub>

Feed version:
[feed story posting http://a.yfrog.com/img203/2576/37p.png](http://a.yfrog.com/img203/2576/37p.png)

Why is this one coming out differently? That's what we want, but the first one won't do it.

And it's not because they're being aggregated. This later one also does that correctly, showing our story text:

Aggregate on Feed:
[multiple feed story http://a.yfrog.com/img203/3096/knl.png](http://a.yfrog.com/img203/3096/knl.png)

Edited 11/15/12:
cross ref this bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/123954517762120 .

Comment: Hey did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No. I haven't worked on this in over 2.5 years -- it was from my startup which I had to shut down.